# SQL for finding unique values in multiply groups

Tags: sql, sparkr

Stuck on a SQL problem for a databricks applications where I am trying to identify which unique values in one column are in two or more groups.  For example:

```
COL_A  COL_B
 123     A
 234     B
 345     B
 123     B
 456     A
 567     C
 345     C
 345     A
```

The results I seek would tell me that unique value 123 was found in both groups A and B, and 345 was found in groups B, C, and A.  Something like ...

```
123   A
123   B
345   B
345   C
345   A
```

or is there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.* FROM myTable a
JOIN(
    SELECT COL_A, COUNT(COL_B)
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY COL_A
    HAVING COUNT(COL_B) > 1
) b on a.COL_A = b.COL_A
ORDER BY COL_A, COL_B
```

Comment: All makes sense except the lower case a and b's.  

b on a.COL_A = b.COL_A ?

Comment: those are just alias names that I gave to the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `col_a` with multiple `col_b` by doing:

```
select col_a
from t
group by col_a
having min(col_b) <> max(col_b);
```

You can then incorporate this in a query to get the original data:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select col_a
      from t
      group by col_a
      having min(col_b) <> max(col_b)
     ) tt
     on t.col_a = tt.col_a;
```

Comment: I see a typo. I assume you meant max(col_b);